# How to replace Null with "N/A" in column with DATETIME data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to replace all null values in a column of a table with "N/A", but the column has a data types of DATETIME, and I am unsure of how to alter my CASE statement so that all NULL values are replaced with "N/A". Relevant line is starred. Please help!

```
SELECT encounters.patient, encounters.encounterid, encounters.start, 
       extract(year from age(patients.birthdate, encounters.start)),
       CASE
        WHEN deathdate BETWEEN start AND stop THEN 1
        WHEN deathdate NOT BETWEEN start AND stop THEN 0
        WHEN deathdate IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE '0'
       END,
       CASE
        WHEN v1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        WHEN v1 IS NULL THEN 0
       END, 
       CASE
        WHEN v1_90 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        WHEN v1_90 IS NULL THEN 0
       END,
       CASE 
        WHEN startdate_90 IS NOT NULL THEN startdate_90
        **WHEN startdate_90 IS NULL THEN NULL**
       END
FROM encounters JOIN
     patients
     ON encounters.patient = patients.id
```

Comment: You cannot.  `'N/A'` is not a valid integer or date value.

Comment: It is obviously only for displaying

Comment: A case expression's different return values must be of matching data types.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace the values, then the columns need to be strings.  This should work:

```
(CASE WHEN deathdate BETWEEN start AND stop THEN '1'
      WHEN deathdate NOT BETWEEN start AND stop THEN '0'
      WHEN deathdate IS NULL THEN 'N/A'   -- could just be ELSE
 END)
```

If your `THEN` clauses need to refer to a number or date, then you need to convert that value to a string.

Comment: How could I do this for the datetime column? Even if I try to change the datatype to support strings, then the rest of my date values cannot be inserted.

Comment: @Nexpert101 . . . Use `to_char()`.

Comment: @Nexpert101 Cannot be inserted into what?  You said it was just for display purposes.